# Given that $( A_n Z_n )_{n \leq 0}$ converges in $\mathbb{C}$, prove that $\sum (A_n - A_{n+1}) Z_n$ converges iff $\sum A_n (Z_{n} - Z_{n-1})$ does

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

Starting with left implies right.
I want to see that given $\epsilon > 0 $ there's an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ so that for all $i$ , $j \in \mathbb{N}$ with $i > j$

$$ | \sum_{n=1} ^i a_n (Z_n - Z_{n-1}) - \sum_{n=1} ^j a_n (Z_n - Z_{n-1}) | < \epsilon$$

So

$$ | \sum_{n=1} ^i a_n (Z_n - Z_{n-1}) - \sum_{n=1} ^j a_n (Z_n - Z_{n-1}) | = | \sum_{n=j} ^i a_n (Z_n - Z_{n-1}) |$$

$$ = | \sum_{n=j} ^i a_n Z_n - \sum_{n=j} ^i a_n Z_{n-1} | = | \sum_{n=j} ^i a_n Z_n - \sum_{n=j} ^i a_{n+1} Z_n + \sum_{n=j} ^i a_{n+1} Z_n -\sum_{n=j} ^i a_n Z_{n-1} | $$

$$ = | \sum_{n=j} ^i (a_n - a_{n+1}) Z_n + a_iZ_i - a_j Z_j + \sum_{n=j} ^{i-1} a_{n+1} Z_n -\sum_{n=j+1} ^i a_n Z_{n-1} | $$

$$ = | \sum_{n=j} ^i (a_n - a_{n+1}) Z_n + a_iZ_i - a_j Z_j |$$

$$ \leq | \sum_{n=j} ^i (a_n - a_{n+1}) Z_n | + |a_iZ_i - a_j Z_j | $$

Now since $\sum_{n\geq 1} (a_n - a_{n+1}) Z_n$ converges the tail goes to 0, so there's an $n'$ so that $| \sum_{n=j} ^{\infty} (a_n - a_{n+1}) Z_n | < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ which guarantees that $$| \sum_{n=j} ^i (a_n - a_{n+1}) Z_n | < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

And since $(a_n Z_n)_{n\geq 1}$ converges then for a sufficiently large $m'$ we know that for all $i$, $j > m'$ and $ i > j$ $$|a_iZ_i - a_j Z_j|< \frac{\epsilon}{2} $$

So we take $n_0 = max\{ n', m' \}$ and that guarantees

$$ | \sum_{n=j} ^i (a_n - a_{n+1}) Z_n | + |a_iZ_i - a_j Z_j | < \epsilon $$

Is this the correct approach to this kind of problem? I noticed a couple of problems when I was writing this and managed to fix them, but still not sure this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better not to start with epsilons and deltas. Find the manipulations that work and make them rigorous later.

The idea here is that $$\sum_{n=0}^N (A_n - A_{n+1}) Z_n = \sum_{n=0}^N A_n Z_n - \sum_{n=1}^{N+1} A_n Z_{n-1} = A_0 Z_0 - A_{N+1} Z_{N+1} - \sum_{n=1}^{N+1} A_n (Z_n - Z_{n-1}).$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could note that

$A_{n+1}Z_{n+1} - A_n Z_n = (A_{n+1} - A_n) Z_{n} + (Z_{n+1}- Z_n) A_{n+1}$.

The sum of the sequence in left converges since $(A_k Z_k)$ converges. Therefore the sum of one of the sequences in right converges iff the other converges.